# Error while installing CometChat Cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, plugins, cmd, cordova-plugins, cometchat

I need to integrate the CometChat into my Cordova application. So by following https://support.cometchat.com/documentation/php/cordova-chat-plugin-ionic-chat-plugin/adnroid-cordova-ionic-phonegap-chat-plugin/initial-setup/

and for that i have downloaded the SDKs for Android & iOS from https://my.cometchat.com/licenses

But now when i am trying to install the sdk plugins using cmd:

```
cordova platform add 'PATH_TO_MY_LOCAL_FOLDER_HAVING_SDK_PLUGIN_PATH'
```

I am facing error like this:

[image: Error_Screenshot]

How do i resolve the the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either add a `package.json` file to the donwloaded plugin or you can install it with the `--nofetch` flag:

```
cordova/phonegap plugin add <path/to/local/plugin> --nofetch
```

Since cordova 7.0.0 `npm install` is run by default when adding a new plugin which causes an error if no `package.json` is present. You can find the release notes for cordova 7.0.0 [here](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/05/04/cordova-7.html).

Comment: wohoo..!!
it ran seemlessly..!
Thanks a lot..!!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you out!